# OpenCV - No image shown without waitkey in the capture loop

Tags: python, c#, c++, opencv

In *OpenCV*, if I don't include `Cv2.WaitKey(1)` line in the display loop for captured images, no image is rendered on the screen.
The same happens on C++, phyton, or C#.

What would be the cause for that, and is there another option?

This example is in C# (*opencvsharp*):

```
VideoCapture cap = new VideoCapture();

Window w = new Window();    

cap.Open("animation.avi");

while (cap.Read(src)) {
    Cv2.WaitKey(1);
    w.ShowImage(src);
}
```

Comment: @Rama Nah this is more like why you need to call it in order to see an image. I think he knows what it does on his own

Answer (score 1):

Technically `highgui` requires `waitkey()` to be called in order to get time to update the window.

From *OpenCV* documentation referring to `imshow()` function (`ShowImage` in C#):

> This function should be followed by waitKey function which displays
>   the image for specified milliseconds. Otherwise, it won’t display the
>   image. For example, waitKey(0) will display the window infinitely
>   until any keypress (it is suitable for image display). waitKey(25)
>   will display a frame for 25 ms, after which display will be
>   automatically closed. (If you put it in a loop to read videos, it will
>   display the video frame-by-frame)

And about `waitKey()` function (`WaitKey()` in C#):

> This function is the only method in HighGUI that can fetch and handle
>   events, so it needs to be called periodically for normal event
>   processing unless HighGUI is used within an environment that takes
>   care of event processing.

Comment: Could you provide a link or a reference of the OpenCV documentation cited?

Comment: http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/highgui/doc/user_interface.html?highlight=waitkey

Comment: This specific for OpenCV 3.1.0: http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d7/dfc/group__highgui.html#ga5628525ad33f52eab17feebcfba38bd7